# Не могу увидеть механизм создания функциональной пары

Tags: lua, функциональное-программирование

```
function cons(_x, _y)
 return function(m) 
  return (m == 0 and _x) or _y end
end
```

Не могу увидеть как параметр m, возвращает в _x,_y два значения.Как эта функция создает пару?  Конструкция типа `m==0 and _x or _y` возвращает сразу два значения? Вроде одно только? Или аргументы, передаваемые в  x,y по одному проваливаются внутрь и по одному возвращаются?

Comment: Метки незачем дублировать в заголовке. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция возвращает другую функцию, в которую подставляются значения. А эта функция уже возвращает просто результат сравнения и возвращает значение or. Это проще всего увидеть на примерах.

```
local func = cons(10, 20)
```

Породит следующий код

```
local func = function (m)
    return (m == 0 and 10) or 20 
end

print(func(0)) //10
print(func(3)) //20
```

То есть выражение в итоге возвращает только одно значение, а не пару, по логической схеме.

```
return (m == 0 and 10) or 20
```

Это можно переписать так:

```
function cons(_x, _y)
 return function(m) 
   if (m == 0) then
      return _x
   else
      return _y
   end
  end
end


print (cons(10,20)(0)) // 10
print (cons(10,20)(3)) // 20
```

***Как работает выражение return (m == 0 and 10) or 20***

Операция `and` возвращает:

- если все выражение верное, то свой последний аргумент
- если все выражение неверное, то `false`

  ```
  print (2 and 10) // 10
  print (0 and 10) // 10
  print (3 and 0 and 10 and 2) // 2
  print (0 and false and 0 and 0) // false
  print (0 == 1 and 10) // false
  ```

Операция `or` возвращает:

- первый встретившийся `true` аргумент
- если все выражение `false`, то `false`

  ```
  print (2 or 10) // 2
  print (0 or 10) // 0
  print (false or 2 or 10) // 2
  print (false or 0 == 1 or 2) // 2
  print (false or 0 == 1) // false
  ```

Итого мы имеем следующую картину, если `m == 0` то выражение `and` принимает значение `true` и возвращает первый аргумент `_x`. Если же `m != 0` то возвращает второе значение выражение `_y`, так как в `or` первое будет `false`.